# how to set scrolltop by javascript like jquery?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrolltop

My html code:

```
<select class="sss" size="3"> 
       <option value="1">value 1</option> 
       <option value="2">value 2</option> 
       <option value="3">value 3</option> 
       <option value="4">value 4</option> 
       <option value="5">value 5</option> 
       <option value="6">value 6</option> 
 <select>
```

and jquery code:

```
var $s = $('.sss');

var optionTop = $s.find('[value="3"]').offset().top;
var selectTop = $s.offset().top;

$s.scrollTop($s.scrollTop() + (optionTop - selectTop));
```

it is possible for me in jquery . ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kj9p4/))

**but** I want to solve that in javascript. **Is it possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved that:** *following ans:*

```js
var s = document.getElementById("aa");

var optionTop = s.querySelector('option[value="2"]').offsetTop;
var selectTop = s.offsetTop;

s.scrollTop = s.scrollTop + (optionTop - selectTop);
```

```html
<select id="aa" size="3">
  <option value="1">value 1</option>
  <option value="2">value 2</option>
  <option value="3">value 3</option>
  <option value="4">value 4</option>
  <option value="5">value 5</option>
  <option value="6">value 6</option>
<select>
```